# Is there a better way of printing my dice result in my dice roll function?

Tags: python, arrays, dice

So I'm writing a dice_roll function for 2 dices to be rolled for my dice game project, currently I want to include the corresponding dice result in a dice format.

Although the code does work, I was wondering if there was a better way of printing out the dice format instead of putting it through an array like this so that the output doesn't have additional brackets and only shows the dice result like this:

```
[0   0]
[  0  ]
[0   0]
```

I am a beginner at coding so I'm unsure of any other methods other than arrays.

This is the code I have:

```
def dice_roll(): # rolls 2 six-sided dice
  dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
  print("Dice 1: You rolled a", dice1, "\n"

  if dice1 == 1:
    dice_layer1 = np.array(["[     ]"])
    dice_layer2 = np.array(["[  0  ]"])
    dice_layer3 = np.array(["[     ]"])
    roll_animation = np.array([dice_layer1, dice_layer2, dice_layer3])
    print(roll_animation, "\n")

  elif dice1 == 2:
    dice_layer1 = np.array(["[0    ]"])
    dice_layer2 = np.array(["[     ]"])
    dice_layer3 = np.array(["[    0]"])
    roll_animation = np.array([dice_layer1, dice_layer2, dice_layer3])
    print(roll_animation, "\n")
  
  elif dice1 == 3:
    dice_layer1 = np.array(["[0    ]"])
    dice_layer2 = np.array(["[  0  ]"])
    dice_layer3 = np.array(["[    0]"])
    roll_animation = np.array([dice_layer1, dice_layer2, dice_layer3])
    print(roll_animation, "\n")
    
  elif dice1 == 4:
    dice_layer1 = np.array(["[0   0]"])
    dice_layer2 = np.array(["[     ]"])
    dice_layer3 = np.array(["[0   0]"])
    roll_animation = np.array([dice_layer1, dice_layer2, dice_layer3])
    print(roll_animation, "\n")
  
  elif dice1 == 5:
    dice_layer1 = np.array(["[0   0]"])
    dice_layer2 = np.array(["[  0  ]"])
    dice_layer3 = np.array(["[0   0]"])
    roll_animation = np.array([dice_layer1, dice_layer2, dice_layer3])
    print(roll_animation, "\n")
  
  elif dice1 == 6:
    dice_layer1 = np.array(["[0   0]"])
    dice_layer2 = np.array(["[0   0]"])
    dice_layer3 = np.array(["[0   0]"])
    roll_animation = np.array([dice_layer1, dice_layer2, dice_layer3])
    print(roll_animation, "\n")
```

I then repeat this code but instead for dice2

Comment: Don't create arrays, just use strings. `dice_layer1 = "[     ]"`

Comment: Why do you need an array at all? Why not just use `print` to print what you want?

Comment: And why do you need 3 different variables? Just put newlines in the string: `dice = "[     ]\n[  0  ]\n[     ]"`

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi Thanks for responding so quickly, I must say this flew past right over my head. I originally intended for me to be able to output the dice1 and dice2 result side by side in 1 line rather under each other so I tried to use arrays so that then i can substitute the two arrays into another array so that it outputs like this:  '[          ]' '[          ]' I guess it would be simpler to just print though. Thanks very much

Comment: If you want to do that, it would be easier if you had a list of lines for each die. Then you can loop over them in parallel, printing each line side by side. `for line1, line2 in zip(dice1, dice2): print(line1, line2)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I am a beginner at coding so I'm unsure of any other methods other than arrays." This makes absolutely no sense. The tool you are using right now requires a third-party library, and is **absolutely not** the most "beginner" option available. Any reasonable Python tutorial should have shown you *lists* first, which are built into the language.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sorry I didn't clarify my usage of the numpty library and perhaps it is slightly misleading that I am a beginner although I only have the knowledge of GCSE computer science. I was trying to find ways of using arrays to ouput my dice results so that i could place them side by side and stumbled on this library which allowed me to join the arrays into a single array but I felt that there must have been a better way which led to my question on stack overflow. Sorry if my original comment was misleading

Comment: My point is that you are learning concepts out of order. Please study the fundamentals of the language, and forget that there is such a thing as Numpy, until you are familiar with working in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating your code with `dice1` replaced by `dice2` falls foul of a principle of software development -- [don't repeat yourself!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Instead, create a function that will print a die for a given value. You can define a list that contains *strings* that depict all the faces of the die:

```
die_faces = ["", # index = 0 doesn't have a face
             "[     ]\n[  0  ]\n[     ]", # index 1
             "[0    ]\n[     ]\n[    0]", # index 2
             "[0    ]\n[  0  ]\n[    0]", # index 3
             "[0   0]\n[     ]\n[0   0]", # index 4
             "[0   0]\n[  0  ]\n[0   0]", # index 5
             "[0   0]\n[0   0]\n[0   0]", # index 6
             ]

def print_die(value: int):
    print(die_faces[value])
```

Then, in your function you could do:

```
def dice_roll():
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
    print(f"Die 1: You rolled a {die1}")
    print_die(die1)

    die2 = random.randint(1,6)
    print(f"Die 2: You rolled a {die2}")
    print_die(die2)
```

which prints, e.g.:

```
Die 1: You rolled a 2
[0    ]
[     ]
[    0]
Die 2: You rolled a 3
[0    ]
[  0  ]
[    0]
```

Since you mention that you want to print multiple dice side-by-side, recognize that you need to print the first lines of each die first, then the second lines, and then the third lines. You can do this quite easily by splitting the lines of each face, and then iterating over the `zip` of the resulting lists.

```
def print_dice(values: list[int]):
    faces = [die_faces[v].splitlines() for v in values]
    for line in zip(*faces):
        print(*line)
```

Now, you can call this function like:

```
print_dice([1, 2, 3])
```

which will print:

```
[     ] [0    ] [0    ]
[  0  ] [     ] [  0  ]
[     ] [    0] [    0]
```

Implementing this in your function,

```
def dice_roll(num_dice=2): # rolls `num_dice` six-sided dice
    all_dice = [random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(num_dice)]
    print(f"You rolled ", all_dice)
    print_dice(all_dice)
```

and calling it with, e.g.

```
dice_roll(3)
```

```
You rolled  [2, 5, 2]
[0    ] [0   0] [0    ]
[     ] [  0  ] [     ]
[    0] [0   0] [    0]
```

Comment: Thanks, this cleared up most of my thoughts, this might be a hassle but is there a page on finding about what the zip function does as I have not encountered it before and also a page on declaring functions when passing through a variable as I have not used the slightly more advanced way of passing multiple values through a function.

Comment: The documentation is usually helpful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip Functions are usually covered well by most tutorials you'll find online

Comment: also why does the ouput have 3 dice results when we have the num_dice variable set to 2? And what is the meaning of the f at the start of the print statement? Many thanks for the guidance though.

Comment: @chenn_jr I called the function as `dice_roll(3)`. See my edit

Comment: @chenn_jr the f at the start of the string literal denotes that it is a f-string literal. https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary to store all the dot positions so you don't have to repeat your code all the time:

```py
dice_dict = {
    1: [4],
    2: [0, 8],
    3: [0, 4, 8],
    4: [0, 2, 6, 8],
    5: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
    6: [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8]
}

for roll, dots in dice_dict.items():
    for i in range(0, 9, 3):
        print(f'[{" ".join(["0" if j in dots else " " for j in range(i, i+3)])}]')
    print()
```

This example will print all dice in order.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the visual representation can be documented within a string.

A simplified version of your code would be to put each dice string into a list, then use your random int to get the index of the corresponding dice:

```
def roll_dice():
    sides = ["[     ]\n[  0  ]\n[     ]", "[0    ]\n[     ]\n[    0]", "[0    ]\n[  0  ]\n[    0]", "[0   0]\n[     ]\n[0   0]", "[0   0]\n[  0  ]\n[0   0]", "[0   0]\n[0   0]\n[0   0]"]
    rolled_number = random.randint(1,6)
    return rolled_number, sides[rolled_number - 1]

def play_game():
    roll1, dice1 = roll_dice()
    roll2, dice2 = roll_dice()

    print(f"Dice 1: You rolled a {roll1}!\n{dice1}\n\nDice 2: You rolled a {roll2}!\n{dice2}")

play_game()
```

Output:

```
Dice 1: You rolled a 3!
[0    ]
[  0  ]
[    0]

Dice 2: You rolled a 2!
[0    ]
[     ]
[    0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fun question. You can leverage symmetry:

```
def animate_dice(r: int) -> str:
    c='|'+'o '[r<1]+' '+'o '[r<3]+'|\n|'+'o '[r<5]
    print(c+'o '[r&1]+c[::-1])
```

NB: starts at 0:

```
>>> animate_dice(dice1 - 1)
|o o|
| o |
|o o|
```